# How to use an Alert in a saga, suspending it, and only proceed if the button is pressed?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, redux-saga

I'm not very familiar with redux-saga yet. I'm trying to use an Alert in a saga function in case of timeout response from API. I'm forcing the return of a timeout and the Alert is working.

However, the saga continues. I don't know how to pause it and only proceed if the user press "Ok" button on Alert. My intention is to show connection or API problems in an Alert or Modal and only go on if it is restored.

```js
function* sagaExample (action) {

    // code

    const response = yield call(apiRequest, data) // It will return "TIMEOUT" string in case of timeout

    if (response === "TIMEOUT") {

        var timeout = yield call(function* () {

            try {
                Alert.alert(
                    "No connection",
                    "Message",
                     [{text: "OK", onPress: function() { return true }}], // I want this function to make Saga continue
                     {cancelable: true},
                )
            } catch(error) {
                return error
            }
        });
    }

    console.log(timeout) // It returns undefined

    if (timeout) {
      // it never runs
    }

    // code
}
```

This is one of the attempts using `try/catch`. I tried different similar approaches like calling a generator function.
I searched a lot, but I don't know what I'm missing. I'm not sure how to make it really suspends the saga function and respond to the Alert button appropriately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a wrapper for your `Alert` call that resolves a promise once it has finished:

```
function wrappedAlert() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    Alert.alert(
                "No connection",
                "Message",
                 [{text: "OK", onPress: function() { resolve(); }}], // I want this function to make Saga continue
                 {cancelable: true, onDismiss: function() {resolve(); }},
            )
    });
}


const response = yield call(apiRequest, data) // It will return "TIMEOUT" string in case of timeout

if (response === "TIMEOUT") {

    var timeout = yield call(wrappedAlert);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, your answer fit well to my situation.

Answer (score 3):

Sagas have builtin support for waiting for promises, so i would wrap this in a promise and yield it:

```
if (response === 'TIMEOUT') {
  yield new Promise((resolve) => {
    Alert.alert(
      'No connection',
      'Message',
      [{ text: "OK", onPress: resolve }],
      { cancelable: true },
    );
  });
}
```